# Python Login Script

Tags: python, authentication

I know similar questions have been asked, I have read them. I have also read most other related articles I could find. I have tried httplib2, header modifications, and anything else I could find or think of, however I cannot get this login script to work.

```
import cookielib
import urllib
import urllib2

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
resp = opener.open('http://www.biocidecity.com')

theurl = 'http://www.biocidecity.com/index.php'
body={'username':'someusername','password':'somepassword', 'login' : '1'}
txdata = urllib.urlencode(body) txheaders =  {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'}


try:
    req = urllib2.Request(theurl, txdata, txheaders)
    handle = opener.open(req) 
    HTMLSource = handle.read()
    f = file('test.html', 'w')
    f.write(HTMLSource)
    f.close()

except IOError, e:
    print 'We failed to open "%s".' % theurl
    if hasattr(e, 'code'):
        print 'We failed with error code - %s.' % e.code
    elif hasattr(e, 'reason'):
        print "The error object has the following 'reason' attribute :", e.reason
        print "This usually means the server doesn't exist, is down, or we don't have an internet connection."
        sys.exit()

else:
    print 'Here are the headers of the page :'
    print handle.info()
```

First this is not my script however I have modified it some. Second I think it has something to do with the way the cookies are handled but I can't figure it out. I also replaced the username password combination.

Comment: "I cannot get this login script to work".  You should perhaps define what it **is** doing and why you don't like that.  Does it have Syntax Errors?  Does it return a 401 error from the web server?  What are you seeing as the result?

Comment: My mistake, when I view the interaction in Wireshark the server simply returns the same login page that I posted to (i.e. I am not redirected). Other than that no errors, nothing. The only difference I can find is when I submit the form in Chrome the 302 response packet contains cookie information in the http header and it does not when I use the script... hmmm maybe I should reword my question.

Comment: "maybe I should reword my question".  Absolutely.  Please **update** the question to be very clear on what problem you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it's again term of service but you should try

```
import cookielib
import urllib
import urllib2

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
resp = opener.open('http://www.biocidecity.com')

theurl = 'http://www.biocidecity.com/index.php'
body={'username':'someusername','password':'somepassword', 'login' : '1'}
txdata = urllib.urlencode(body) txheaders =  {'Referer': 'http://www.biocidecity.com/index.php'}


try:
    req = urllib2.Request(theurl, txdata, txheaders)
    handle = opener.open(req) 
    HTMLSource = handle.read()
    f = file('test.html', 'w')
    f.write(HTMLSource)
    f.close()

except IOError, e:
    print 'We failed to open "%s".' % theurl
    if hasattr(e, 'code'):
        print 'We failed with error code - %s.' % e.code
    elif hasattr(e, 'reason'):
        print "The error object has the following 'reason' attribute :", e.reason
        print "This usually means the server doesn't exist, is down, or we don't have an internet connection."
        sys.exit()

else:
    print 'Here are the headers of the page :'
    print handle.info()
```